# Complex vector space, but with a real inner product (Hilbert sub-spaces...?)

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Say I have a complex-valued vector space $\mathbb{C}^n$ with the following inner product:

$$
\langle u,v\rangle=u^Tv
$$

If one picks only vectors that have real entries, and only allow linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$.

Then, can we say that this complex vector space embeds a real Hilbert sub-space, in some sense?

Comment: You need $u^\dagger v$ for the inner product, not $u^Tv$. They're different. That said, $\Bbb C^n$ is a complex inner product space, which turns into a real inner product space with inner product ${\rm Re}(u^\dagger v)$, and then $\Bbb R^n$ is a real inner product (sub)space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of a vector space includes the field over which the elements of the vector space are included.  Since you’re saying you’re vector space is $\mathbb{C}^N$, you’re implicitly saying that your vector space is over the complex values.  A property of a vector space is that a vector from the space multiplied by any scalar from the field is also in the space.  Therefore, if you give me a real vector, I must be able to multiply it by i and that vector is also in the space.

So this contradicts the idea that you can only choose real vectors.  Once you give me a real vector, I can make complex vectors that lie in the space.

Note that if you had defined your inner product to be $Re\{u^* v\}$, then you would you have an inner product space that is equivalent to the inner product space of $\mathbb{R}^{2N}$ and the regular dot product.  So that is a Hilbert space.